# issues with Transient Attributes Using Groovy Expressions on MySQL db

Tags: mysql, groovy, oracle-adf

I'm using JDevelper 11.1.2.4 and MySql DB 5.6.19. The version of JConnector I am using is mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.

I've created two tables `country` and `city`.

In table `city`, there is foreign key to link it with the `country` table.

JDevelper have created associations and view links for these tables which I've tested using ADF Model Tester and they are looking fine.

I've created a transient column *CountryName* and set the default value (as Expression) to *Country1.CountryName*.

Now when I run the ADF Model Tester again, I get the following error:

```
(oracle.jbo.SQLStmtException) JBO-27122: SQL error during statement preparation.  
Statement: 
SELECT CountryEO.country_id, CountryEO.country_name, CountryEO.country_code, 
CountryEO.country_short_name, CountryEO.currency_id, CountryEO.created_date,     
CountryEO.created_by, CountryEO.last_updated_date, CountryEO.last_updated_by 
FROM cms.country CountryEO WHERE CountryEO.country_id = ?

----- Level 1: Detail 0 -----

(com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException) 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=1' at line 1
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: no, i am using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver which is referring to mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin

Answer (score 0):

Please check your country view object query by sql puls / toad etc. If its correct please post your question